# Shell script to convert a date string to specific timestamp format

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, datetime-format

I have a date time string like this `17-Mar-2020.22:22 -0300`.I want to get the output as `2020-03-17 22:12` .

The timezone offset is causing an issue as without that I am able to convert

For example `DATE=17-Mar-2020.22:22
    date -jf "%d-%b-%Y.%H:%M" $DATE "+date \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\""`

But this timezone offset is causing an issue.Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

Because the input is in an unusual format, it needs to be first formatted to a format `date` can eat. I use the format indicated in man page `"2004-02-29 16:21:42"` or `"Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"`. GNU date allows for very flexible input format - don't trust it.

Below I used `sed` to match the input and reformat it.

```
input='17-Mar-2020.22:22 -0300'
input2="$(sed 's/\([0-9]*\)-\([^-]*\)-\([^\.]*\)\.\([0-9]*\):\([0-9]*\)/\1 \2 \3 \4:\5:00/' <<<"$input")"
# input2="17 Mar 2020 22:22:00 -0300"
date --date="$input2" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
# 2020-03-18 02:22
```

> date -jf

[GNU date](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) differs a lot from [BSD date](https://man.openbsd.org/date.1). They are completely different. BSD date supports the `-j` and `-f` options, GNU date does not.

There are [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) and they include `strptime` utility that allows to do what you wanted to do with date:

```
strptime -e -f "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M\n" -i "%d-%b-%Y.%H:%M %Z" "17-Mar-2020.22:22 -0300"
```

Comment: --I am getting ```date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]``` both in bash as well is macosx terminal. in this line ```date --date="$input2" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"```